# How to use forwardedAs prop with styled-components? Using forwardedAs prop with typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, styled-components, react-props

Here are the docs on `forwardedAs` prop: https://styled-components.com/docs/api#forwardedas-prop.

As you can see, it's not very detailed and does not show how to properly use this prop.

My **question** is: How can I access the props that are sent down via `forwardedAs`? How can I define types for these `forwardedAs` props?

I'm able to access the `forwardedAs` props via `...rest` parameters, but I need to define types for these props since I am also using styled-components with Typescript.

Here's my code example:

```
// Button.jsx
const myPropsToForward = {
  href: 'https://somewebsite.com',
  // ...more props
}

const Button = styled.button`
  // ...button styles
`

const myComponent = () => (
  <Button
    as={Link}
    to={ctaLink}
    forwardedAs={myPropsToForward}
  />
)
```

```
// Link.jsx
const Link = ({
  forwardedAs,
  ...rest
}) => {
  // How do I access the forwardedAs prop from <Button /> here?

  return (
    <a href={forwardAs?.href} {...rest} />
  )
}
```

Here, I need to be able to access the props within the `Link` component sent down via `forwardedAs` prop, but there's no documentation on how to do that. If I can access the `forwardedAs` prop, I can then define proper types for the `Link` component. I do not want to rely on the `...rest` parameter as I cannot define types for that.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: lso as a bonus question, how would I define types for this forwardedAs prop on the Link component?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### forwardedAs

The `forwardedAs` prop is not for passing down props.  It's actually for passing down an `as` prop to the next item in the chain.  Consider this example:

```
const Button = styled.button`
  padding: 20px;
`;

const Link = (props: any) => { // not properly typed
  return <Button {...props} />;
};

const MyLink = styled(Link)`
  background-color: blue;
`

const MyComponent = () => (
  <MyLink forwardedAs={"div"}>
    Text
  </MyLink>
);
```

We have a `Button` which is a styled component and we have a `MyLink` which is another styled component that passes its props down to the `Button`.  If we want to set the `as` prop on the `Button`, we can set `forwardedAs` on `MyLink`.

With `<MyLink forwardedAs={"div"}>`, the element that we ultimately render to the DOM is a `div` rather than a `button` and it applies the styles from both `styled` HOCs.

### Passing Props

Based on your example here, the `Link` component is not actually needed.  You can set `as="a"` on your `Button` to render it as a link and pass through `myPropsToForward` directly.

```
const myPropsToForward = {
  href: "https://somewebsite.com"
  // ...more props
};

const Button = styled.button`
  background: yellow;
  padding: 20px;
`;

const MyComponent = () => (
  <Button as="a" {...myPropsToForward}>
    Text
  </Button>
);
```

Comment: Okay, but what's the actual proper use of `forwardedAs`?

Comment: The use of `forwardedAs` is to set the `as` prop on the second-level deep styled component.  In my example, it sets the `as` component on `Button = styled.button` rather than on `const MyLink = styled(Link)`.